# Proper workflow for testing a julia package locally on multiple versions of Base at once

Tags: julia

It is very common for Julia packages to support multiple version of Julia at once. The standard workflow is make modifications in `~/.julia/v0.x/PackageName` and then run `Pkg.test("PackageName")` on the package, but this only tests the package in whatever Julia 0.x is and not other versions. The other versions can't see the local changes since the modifications were only made in 0.x folder. Currently, I rely on Travis on catching problems, but the turn around time is much slower than running tests locally.

What is the proper method for testing a package on multiple versions of Julia locally? Symbolic links?

Comment: I've been using symbolic links.

Answer (score 1):

Use symbolic links.

I've been using symbolic links since `julia v0.3`. It works reasonably well. I'll typically have the package checked out in the lower version directory, (say 0.4), and have symbolic links in the directories for 0.5 and 0.6. I do this for all packages that I'm actively working on. Everything else get duplicated as part of the Pkg.add/clone process.

This only works of course when you have a single branch of your package (typicaly master) that supports all julia versions, via Compat. In cases where you have different branches for different julia versions, you'll need to have separate checkouts for each julia version.